Error message in Python script when using fast_ml library
I am getting an error message "NameError: name 'display_all' is not defined" when I run the Python script as given below.I am using Thonny 4.1.2 on Windows 11 using Python 3.The code is as given below.Please help me.I have imported all the necessary modules and functions in the library.
from fast_ml import eda
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
train = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Amarjeet Jayanthi\Desktop\Quesba\Skill Genie\Project\emails.csv')
summary_df = eda.df_info(train)
print(summary_df)
info=eda.df_info(train)
print(info)
cardinality=eda.df_cardinality_info(train,raw_data=True)
print(cardinality)
missing=eda.df_missing_info(train,raw_data=True)
print(missing)

